# How to find the students number within specified date in aws s3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to find the total number of students that have the files within the folder of s3. I have the directory structure as:

```
s3://bucket/student=10/year=2019/month=05/...
```

Suppose the date is year=2019, month=06 then I want to find the total number of students id with the files present inside the folder with above dates.

I am using boto3 in python.

```
        s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
        ob = s3.Bucket("bucket")
        dic = {}
        dic["total students"] = []
        for n in range(5):
            date = end_date - timedelta(days=n)
            date = date.strftime(f'year=%Y/month=%m/')

            for obj in ob.objects.filter(Prefix=f'/student_id={student_id}/{date}'):

                  .....
                if student_id not in dic["total students"]:
                    dic["total students"+student_id].append(student_id)
```

However, I think this is not a good approach. Is there any way to count the number of students directly

Comment: I've never seen S3 used as a "database" but yes, it looks like this is about as good as you'll do.  This is certainly not the most efficient setup but that's not the fault of your code.

Comment: Not unless you use S3 bucket alarm trigger to put the file name into some sort of database or log. If the S3 is somewhat static, you may use cloudwatch to generate an inventories log and access from there.